# Why .html() don't output html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i have a p element

```
<p> simple text <h3> this is h3 text </h3> </p>
```

And  i do this.

```
 alert($('p').html());
```

It should give output  `simple text <h3> this is h3 text</h3>`

But it alerts only `simple text`. I thought Ok may be `.html()` does not output html tags

But when i add any html using jquery in same p element , And then alert in same way it gives me result which is expected(it shows html tags as well) .

This is example

https://jsfiddle.net/04f1drby/

Can someone explain why this different behaviour ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Because `<p> simple text <h3> this is h3 text </h3> </p>` is invalid HTML. In your own fiddle, inspect the rendered code and see how the browser tries to fix the invalid HTML for you.

Comment: @BuhBuh Some people want to help others and are not motivated by imaginary internet points...

Comment: there's probably already multiple answers to this question on here anyway

Comment: @BuhBuh Click on j08691's username. They've got 131K. Also, this question will likely be closed as a typo or non-reproducible error.

Comment: You can see that the HTML is invalid on the fiddle itself: the misplaced `</p>` has a red background.

Comment: @JJJ yeah I was thinking why it is showing red ? .

Comment: @freedomn-m I had more trust on myself

Comment: @JJJ But i am still confused , why in the second case , it works. i mean then also <h1> is added inside p element

Comment: @beginner It looks like your question should have been: "why does jquery allow `h` tags inside a `p` tag when the browser does not" ...   the second is generated by jquery so perhaps does not have the same rules applied for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into chrome inspector for the JS fiddle page you linked you'll notice the HTML gets rendered as this:

```
<p id="firstp">
simple text</p><h3>
this is h3 text
</h3>
<p></p>
```

A closing paragraph tag is added just before your starting header tag.